# How to fix npm audit issues and unable to find npm plugin in rug.config in eclipse after installation

Tags: node.js, npm-install, npm-audit

When I run npm audit fix it says fixed 0 of 2 vulnerabilities in 11294 scanned packages 2 vulnerabilities required manual review and could not be updated. Please provide any suggestion to resolve the this issue.

C:\Users\saivenkateswar.k\Pictures\botium-sample-eclipse-master\botium-sample-eclipse-master>npm audit fix

npm WARN botium-sample-watson@2.0.0 No repository field.

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 (node_modules\fsevents):

npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.7: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"}) up to date in 35.383s

fixed 0 of 2 vulnerabilities in 11294 scanned packages
  2 vulnerabilities required manual review and could not be updated

C:\Users\saivenkateswar.k\Pictures\botium-sample-eclipse-master\botium-sample-eclipse-master>npm audit

```
                   === npm audit security report ===


                             Manual Review
         Some vulnerabilities require your attention to resolve

      Visit https://go.npm.me/audit-guide for additional guidance
```

Moderate           Sandbox Breakout / Arbitrary Code Execution

Package            static-eval

Patched in         No patch available

Dependency of      botium-bindings [dev]

Path               botium-bindings > botium-core > jsonpath > static-eval

More info          https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/758

Moderate           Sandbox Breakout / Arbitrary Code Execution

Package            static-eval

Patched in         No patch available

Dependency of      botium-cli [dev]

Path               botium-cli > botium-core > jsonpath > static-eval

More info          https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/758

found 2 moderate severity vulnerabilities in 11294 scanned packages
  2 vulnerabilities require manual review. See the full report for deta

Comment: We are aware of these vulnerability warnings. You cannot do anything about it yourself, only the package maintainers.

Comment: Ok. Please provide some suggestions to the run botium scripts as "npm test"

Comment: If you have no basic knowledge of how NPM, Node.js, Mocha work, then you won't get happy with Botium Bindings and Botium CLI - either gain some knowledge on it, or use Botium Box (we especially built it as low-level entry)